# Multiple PWM Generation using PI Controller

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pwm, pid-controller, proteus

I am using dual loop to control dc-dc boost converter using Arduino Uno in Proteus. The kp and ki work fine for individual implementation of each boost converter. But when I combine them like this, I get same PWM generated for every boost. Even though the current_s, current_w, current_b is different for each other.

I am not sure why same PWM is generated for each boost when it has to be different because of different values of parameters. Does this has to do something with the way I have implemented PI functions?

````
// PI Parameters
double kp_boost = 0.002657;
double ki_boost = 0.4;

double setPoint = 2;

double error_s = 0;
double error_w = 0;
double error_b = 0;

double error_1_s = 0;
double error_1_w = 0;
double error_1_b = 0;

double voltage_sense = 0;
double voltage_sense_s = 0;
double voltage_sense_w = 0;
double voltage_sense_b = 0;

double current_s = 0;
double current_w = 0;
double current_b = 0;

double output_s;
double output_w;
double output_b;

int PWM_s = 9;
int PWM_w = 10;
int PWM_b = 11;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
  voltage_sense_s = (5 * analogRead(A0)) / 1023;
  current_s = voltage_sense_s / 0.1; 

  voltage_sense_w = (5 * analogRead(A1)) / 1023;
  current_w = voltage_sense_w / 0.1;   

  voltage_sense_b = (5 * analogRead(A2)) / 1023;
  current_b = voltage_sense_b / 0.1;   

  voltage_sense = (5 * analogRead(A3)) / 1023;


// calling PI Functions  
  double PMW_s = PI_s(voltage_sense);
  double PMW_w = PI_w(voltage_sense);
  double PMW_b = PI_b(voltage_sense);

// Calculation Duty Cycle Value
  double dutycycle_s = PMW_s - current_s;
  double dutycycle_w = PMW_w - current_w;
  double dutycycle_b = PMW_b - current_b;

 // Generating PWM
  analogWrite(PWM_s, dutycycle_s);
  analogWrite(PWM_w, dutycycle_w);
  analogWrite(PWM_b, dutycycle_b);

  delay(0.1);
}

// PI Functions
double PI_s(double inp) {
  error_s = setPoint - inp;
  output_s += kp_boost * (error_s - error_1_s) + ki_boost * error_s; 
  error_1_s = error_s;
  return output_s;
}

double PI_w(double inp) {
  error_w = setPoint - inp;
  output_w += kp_boost * (error_w - error_1_w) + ki_boost * error_w; 
  error_1_w = error_w;
  return output_w;
}

double PI_b(double inp) {
  error_b = setPoint - inp;
  output_b += kp_boost * (error_b - error_1_b) + ki_boost * error_b; 
  error_1_b = error_b;
  return output_b;
}
```
````

Comment: All three calculation functions are fed with the same input value and therefore calculate identical results.

Comment: @Jens I tried different variables for same input value and the result was same. The reason for the same input is because of topology used.